# Typescript cannot filter array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, list, filter

I am trying to filter an array of type object, to get the total amount of each value specified.

My object is as follows:

```
export class Member {
  public firstName: string;
  public lastName: string;
  public email: string;
}
```

And my array is defined: `members: Member[] = []`. This is then filled with `Member` objects, from a `.csv` upload. I need to ensure that there are no missing fields in the csv, so my approach was as follows:

Get the number of items that have a first name, last name, and email.

```
const firstNames = this.members.filter(item => item.firstName != null).length;
    const lastNames = this.members.filter(item => item.lastName != null).length;
    const emails = this.members.filter(item => item.email != null).length;
```

However, I get the error `ERROR TypeError: this.members.filter is not a function`.

I have seen people say that `.filter()` doesn't work on Lists, but haven't I declared an Array?

The data is assigned to `members` as follows:

```
this.uploader.response.subscribe(res => { 
const handledResponse = this.memberService.handleUploaderResponse(res); this.error = '';
this.members = handledResponse as Member[];
this.finalUploadCheck(); });
```

Comment: The error message means that *at run-time* the value of `this.members` does not have a `.filter()` method. This usually means that there is a type assertion somewhere that lied to the compiler about what was assigned to that property. Do ***not*** use type assertions unless absolutely necessary to avoid problems like this.

Comment: this.members certainly isn't an array... Also, why do 3 filters? If you want to make sure all three are filled you should have only one filter with the three conditions!

Comment: Please provide more information. Where exactly are these statements executed?

Comment: @Salketer how do you mean it is not an array? How else is an array declared?

Comment: @MichaelD Hi, ``members`` is declared just after the class opening, when a user uploads their CSV, the members is assigned the data, in the form of Member objects. This then calls a method that checks the data is suitable, then processes the data further. And the CSV upload and everything after the checks are made works, I am only just implementing these checks now.

Comment: "_This then calls a method that checks the data_" - exactly. How is this triggered? I have a good guess that it's passed as a callback without the reference to the outer scope's (class') `this`. Please post the code of what you've just explained

Comment: `handledResponse as Member[]` → this should be the root of the problem. Don't just assert the type, make sure handledResponse actually has the right type.

Comment: @Clashsoft I am not sure I quite understand what you mean, could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can't just cast using `as Member[]` and expect it to work. If `handledResponse` is not an array containing Member objects at runtime it will fail silently (and the error will become apparent in a different place, like you are experiencing). What is the return type of `handleUploaderResponse`?

Comment: Arrays are declared with `=` not with `as`. The `as` typescript keyword is just to tell typescript that you know (read THINK) that it is an array. If you console.log the return value of the `handleUploaderResponse()` call you'll see it is not an array. Typical error would make me assume it is a promise.

Comment: @Clashsoft thanks I appreciate the help, your comment made me realise what was wrong. One of my conditions is that the csv must not be empty, and I have been trying to check this in my ``finalUploadCheck()`` method, where as I should be checking this first, before calling the method.

Comment: it's not recommended to use inner observables! try to use mergMap() operator for more readability and performance for your code!